# jasmine no pending request to flush POST

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

so I have the following test in jasmine:

```
    $httpBackend.whenPOST('/api/userdata/saveuser').respond({ 'result': 'true' })

it('should save the new or updated user', function () {
        var controller = createController();
        $httpBackend.flush();
        spyOn(controller, 'saveUser');

        controller.saveUser();
        $httpBackend.flush();
        expect(controller.saveUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
```

When I go to perform the FLUSH after the saveUser I get the famous 'no pending requests to flush'. The controller function looks like the following:

```
  user.saveUser = function () {
          userDataService.saveUser(user.data).then(function (result) {
             $state.go("license", { guid: user.data.user.account });
        });
    };
```

Of course notice that I am not using $scope anywhere in my controller.

Don't get it!! I tried to put some console.log statements in the controller to see if it was hitting it... and I don't see it going into the procedure. YET the expect(controller.saveUser).toHaveBeenCalled() is successful.

Here is the dataservice:

```
function saveUser(user) {
            return $http.post("/api/userdata/saveuser", user.data).success(returndata).error(returnerror)
        };
```

UGGH Why is this happening????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got `$httpBackend.flush();` in your test twice. The first one is the one that's likely causing the error. Remove that line. You don't want to `flush()` until after you've done something that's flushable.

Also, you're spying on the method that you're testing. Remove that line too, or at least change it to:

```
spyOn(controller, 'saveUser').and.callThrough();
```

It doesn't actually make sense to spy that method. You know it'll work because your test calls that function directly.

Comment: yeah just caught that ... what I really need is a expectPOST check to ensure that the POST is performed... thanks!!